# Parsing multipart/mixed response from Curl request in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am making an API call to a third party. Their response contains the `Content-Type` of `multipart/mixed`

The response is made up of some JSON data and then also a PDF.

Is there a way to parse the output so I can access the two parts individually? I could write some code to use a regex but this seems ugly and prone to error.

##### Example response:

```
--uuid:edec021d-b138-4eca-9897-003b7e33e246
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <jsonInfos>

{"messages":[{"id":"0","type":"INFOS","messageContent":"La requête a été traitée avec succès","replacementValues":[]}],"labelXmlV2Reponse":null,"labelV2Response":{"parcelNumber":"8R46623806858","parcelNumberPartner":null,"pdfUrl":null,"fields":null}}
--uuid:edec021d-b138-4eca-9897-003b7e33e246
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <label>

%PDF-1.4
%????
3 0 obj <</Length 556>>stream
0 J
...........
w!1AQaq"2B????  #3R?br?
$4?%?&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
168559
%%EOF

--uuid:edec021d-b138-4eca-9897-003b7e33e246--
```

Comment: Googling "php parse multipart/mixed" found this: https://github.com/Riverline/multipart-parser

Comment: Most hits are for parsing multipart/form-data. It's pretty unusual for an API to return multipart/mixed, that's almost exclusively used in email, not APIs.

Comment: You could read it one line at a time and then look for certain things in each line,  such as `Content-Type`    etc...   Likely the format wont change much.  I wouldn't try to use a `regex` on the "whole" document.  But there is a structure to it you can use to your advantage.  For example once you find `Content-Type: application/json` you know to look for a line that starts with the `{` or the `[`

Comment: PHP has a few assorted functions to deal with MIME encoding (look for [mime](https://https://www.php.net/mime) in the documentation). In particular, I think the IMAP extension can deal with this. I also wouldn't be surprised if some third-party HTTP client has this feature.